# full browser simulation with domtree

Tags: c#, dom, browser, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to simulate the browser fully in a programatical way without interface and need to access every aspect of it. such as DOM Tree , js execution and etc.

I've read phantomjs and casperjs documentation and seems they don't support dom tree.
what do you recommend?

Comment: PhantomJS supports the DOM just fine.  What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: couldn't find example.

Comment: Example for what?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: for example walking through dom tree of rendered page and print the values.

Comment: I don't think you actually read the documentation.  It's just JavaScript.  http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said before, Casperjs handles rendering the domtree any way you would like, list all the anchors, titles, headers etc.. In the old days you would just use something like Python's Beautifulsoup or Perl's TokeParser, but neither of those stand up to the heavy ajax sites we see nowadays.

I would check out the documentation with CasperJs.  It's one of the best tools for scraping the modern web.